# Setting up IIS 7 webserver - have static ip and port forwarding, what could be wrong?

Tags: iis-7

I am trying to set up a simple website on an IIS 7 server on my home machine.  It is going to have light traffic and will only be up for a little while so I don't want to go the commercial hosting route.  I am having trouble accessing the site from outside of my local network.  So far my setup is:

IIS 7 with the default iis7 page (this is sort of my control/test page)
Static IP
port forwarding on port 1108 from my extermal ip:1108 to my static internal ip:1108

Any idea what could be wrong?  My friends who are trying to connect say that they are not getting a "could not connect to server" error on their end.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If this is a standard iis install it is running on port 80 and not 1108.

Also check if "windows firewall" is enabled on your network connection. If the firewall is on it should allow http traffic (under 'allowed programs and features')

Comment: I got it working...I was n00bishly using my internal ip.  I did have it set up properly, firewall was down, etc.  Thanks for the help!